# PostgreSQL fdw performance issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance, postgres-fdw

When I'm querying in PostgreSQL where I have used same foreign table in both from clause and where clause I'm getting timeout error. Whereas if I remove where clause and add it as cte it executes in less than a second. Kindly advise if this foreign tables has limitations in querying.

Comment: Show your table schema (including indexes) and queries.

Comment: No limitations.  Postgres is just materializing the remote data in the CTE, so the query is more efficient.

Comment: My query looks like this " select col from foreigntable1 join foreigntable2 on condition where f1.col in (select col from foreigntable2 where col is null) " so basically foreigntable2 is queries twice

Comment: To add the table has very less volume of data 200+ rows

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes), the query you are using and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a simple "explain". [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)